# How to AutoMapper field?

Tags: automapper

I want to map from entity to model

Entity:

```
public class FileEntity
{
    public IList<TagEntity> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public IList<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The fields in TagEntity and TagModel are all the same

How should I mapper that?

Comment: What have you tried, how your automapper config looks like? Do you get exception or null values? How is `TagEntity` and `TagModel` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<TagEntity, TagModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<FileEntity, FileModel>();
```

AutoMapper will automatically map the lists without you having to do anything extra.